# Control audio with a slider

Tags: javascript, audio, volume, audio-player

How to control volume with mouse action when user pull the volume progress up or down in a custom made audio player (Vanilla JS preferred)

Comment: post your code, you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `input` element with [type="range"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range), then listen for the `input` event or `change` event to update the volume. The `change` event will fire when the user stops moving the slider. The `input` event will fire as the slider is being moved.

Example:

```js
let audio = new Audio("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");

// update the volume when the slider is moved
volume.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  audio.volume = e.currentTarget.value / 100;
});

play.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
});
```

```html
<input type="range" id="volume" value="100">
<button type="button" id="play">
Play/Pause Audio
</button>
```